# React state getting set multiple times with blank value

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a simple Todo app in React to understand ReactJS better.

The issue I am facing is that, Clicking on add button first time adds a new item to Todo List but the second time, **it adds a blank entry** with the new entry. The third time it adds **2 blank entries** to state. And this goes on.

The code to add new element:

```
addTodo(){
    $("#newTodo").modal('open');
    $("#saveTodo").on("click", ()=>{
        console.log("Previous State: "+this.state.todoList);
        var text = $("#todoText").val();
        $("#todoText").val('');
        var newTodo = this.state.todoList;
        newTodo.push(text);
        this.setState({todoList: newTodo});
        console.log("Current State: "+this.state.todoList);
    });
}
```

Here is a [Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/vishnuys/pen/oBPqgm)  to my code.

Comment: To avoid insert empty cards, You should take of $("#todoText").val(''); from your code.

Comment: @LucasOliveira That doesn't work, It only adds the same value instead of blank value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short. Add this line

```
$("#saveTodo").off('click');
```

just before you close the dialog, because of you accumulate event handlers on `#save` click - you get calling your handler each time more and more.

Must to say, that its really not good solution to use jquery and bootstrap modal, more over with default html, instead of react jsx. Much more better to use, for exmaple [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) solution, to avoid such unexpected problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your click event on `save button` is being called twice and hence you get two entries. You need to do `.unbind()` on the click event and close the modal on click of save button

```
$("#saveTodo").unbind().click(() => {
        console.log("Previous State: "+this.state.todoList);
        var text = $("#todoText").val();

        var newTodo = [...this.state.todoList];
  console.log(newTodo);
        newTodo.push(text);
  console.log(newTodo);
        this.setState({todoList: newTodo});
        console.log("Current State: "+this.state.todoList);
  $("#newTodo").modal("close")
    });
```

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/mayank_shubham/pen/jyvxaX)**

Comment: Thank you very much, I wanted to know why the save button is being clicked twice on first second click, thrice on third click and so on. Please do share if you know the reason.

Comment: On clicking on +, you are calling addTodo method, and each time it is adding click event on #saveTodo, so clicking event is firing 1 then 2 and then 3 times, and so on.